# how to store an added class which is created by jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this example which adds a class **active** when hit a link. But after a refresh, the class active is gone ofcourse. So i want to store that class locally so that it is remembered when even a refresh is done. How can i achieve that?

```
<div id="links">
<a href="#">Content 1</a>
<br />
<a href="#">Content 2</a>
<br />
<a href="#">Content 3</a>
</div>
```

and

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$('#links a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#links a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fDZ97/55/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a flag in localStorage and check for it whenever the page loads.

```
<div id="links">
  <a data-id="0"></a>
  <a data-id="1"></a>
</div>
```

---

```
$('document').ready(function() {
   if (localStorage.saveActive) {
      $('#links a[data-id="'+localStorage.saveActive+'"]').addClass('active');
   }
   $('#links a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#links a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      localStorage.saveActive = $(this).data('id');
   });
});
```

Comment: i have tested this in a fiddle but it seems not to work: http://jsfiddle.net/creuh/110/ Edit: stupid mistake; the html should be <div id="links"> ofcourse. Now it works fine!

Comment: @JackMaessen Ah yes. If this answers your question consider marking it answered with a checkmark. :)